# Loading and running an external webpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, background, html

I have been asking this question in different places but couldn't get a real answer.
Here is the problem:
Let say I have a web page which is going to serve like google. I mean it will use google at the bacground but foreground will be my page. It will contain a textbox and a button. So a user will come and enter a text that he wants to search and click the button to submit the query. So my webpage will transfer this search text to the google at the background and search the thing in google. It will return the results to my webpage in a different form. `

So the question is, what is the best way of implementing this and more importantly is it possible.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Google Custom Search API: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

You cannot use classic web crawler techniques to get the data from Google since that violates their TOS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Knaģis but google was just an example. I wasn't aware of such violation though. Is this a case for small websites as well? For example ebay like website.
Here is the real question than,
Would my website still violate the rules if I write a client side code for these searches, like JS, just to prevent searches from a single IP which is my server IP in this case? By this way, let say ebay, won't feel anything different because still a single user is searching something?

Can you tell me if